# Asymptotic notations

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

From what I have studied: I have been asked to determine the complexity of a function with respect to another function. i.e. Given `f(n)` and `g(n)`, determine `O(f(n()`. In such cases, I substitute values, compare both of them and arrive at a complexity - using `O(), Theta and Omega notations`.

However, in the `substitution method for solving recurrences`, every standard document has the following lines:

`• [Assume that T(1) = Θ(1).]`

• `Guess O(n3) . (Prove O and Ω separately.)`

• `Assume that T(k) ≤ ck3 for k < n .`

• `Prove T(n) ≤ cn3 by induction.`

How am I supposed to find O and Ω when nothing else (apart from f(n)) is given? I might be wrong (I, definitely am), and any information  on the above is welcome.

Some of the assumptions above are with reference to this problem: `T(n) = 4T(n/2) + n`
, while the basic outline of the steps is for all such problems.

Comment: `"Given f(n) and g(n), determine f(n)"` - maybe a typing mistake (since, if you already have f(n), what's there to do?)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular recurrence is solvable via the Master Theorem, but you can get some feedback from the substitution method. Let's try your initial guess of `cn^3`.

```
T(n)  = 4T(n/2) + n
     <= 4c(n/2)^3 + n
      = cn^3/2 + n
```

Assuming that we choose `c` so that `n <= cn^3/2` for all relevant `n`,

```
T(n) <= cn^3/2 + n
     <= cn^3/2 + cn^3/2
      = cn^3,
```

so `T` is `O(n^3)`. The interesting part of this derivation is where we used a cubic term to wipe out a linear one. Overkill like that is often a sign that we could guess lower. Let's try `cn`.

```
T(n)  = 4T(n/2) + n
     <= 4cn/2 + n
      = 2cn + n
```

This won't work. The gap between the right-hand side and the bound we want is is `cn + n`, which is big Theta of the bound we want. That usually means we need to guess higher. Let's try `cn^2`.

```
T(n)  = 4T(n/2) + n
     <= 4c(n/2)^2 + n
      = cn^2 + n
```

At first that looks like a failure as well. Unlike our guess of `n`, though, the deficit is little o of the bound itself. We might be able to close it by considering a bound of the form `cn^2 - h(n)`, where `h` is `o(n^2)`. Why subtraction? If we used `h` as the candidate bound, we'd run a deficit; by subtracting `h`, we run a surplus. Common choices for `h` are lower-order polynomials or `log n`. Let's try `cn^2 - n`.

```
T(n)  = 4T(n/2) + n
     <= 4(c(n/2)^2 - n/2) + n
      = cn^2 - 2n + n
      = cn^2 - n
```

That happens to be the exact solution to the recurrence, which was rather lucky on my part. If we had guessed `cn^2 - 2n` instead, we would have had a little credit left over.

```
T(n)  = 4T(n/2) + n
     <= 4(c(n/2)^2 - 2n/2) + n
      = cn^2 - 4n + n
      = cn^2 - 3n,
```

which is slightly smaller than `cn^2 - 2n`.